# how to get data form databse into html table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

[result i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp46Q.png)

hello eveyone,

Ik was being with a project for my school and now im trying to get data from the database into an html table using  php.
This is my code now:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Algemene gegevens gedetineerden</title>
</head>
<body>

        <table border="1" cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</strong></th>
                <th>Naam</strong></th>
                <th>Adres</strong></th>
                <th>Geslacht</strong></th>
                <th>Telefoon</strong></th>
                <th>Email</strong></th>
                <th>Woonplaats</strong></th>
                <th>Geboortedatum</strong></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php
            /*function mysql_connect(){

            };
            function mysql_select_db(){

            };*/

            /*mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("geen verbinding met database");
            mysql_select_db("pro07") or die("kan database niet vinden");*/
            define('HOST','localhost');
            define('DATABASE','pro07');
            define('USER','root');
            define('PASSWORD','');
            //stap2-connectie
            try{
            $conn=mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
            echo ("connection succeed!");
            
            }
            catch(mysqi_sql_exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
                exit;
                echo "connection failed!";
            }

            $query="SELECT id,naam,adres,geslacht,telefoon,email,woonplaats,geboortedatum FROM alggegevens;";
            /*$query="SELECT * FROM alggegevens;"; >>>vanaf regel 57 alle namen in tabel met hoofdletter,bij query hierboven niet
            .hoe je het in de query zet.zo moet het ook inde table rows staan */

            function mysql_query(){

            };
            $resultaat = mysql_query($query);
            function mysql_fetch_array(){

            };
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultaat)) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php print($row["id"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row["naam"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row["adres"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row["geslacht"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row["telefoon"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row["email"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row["woonplaats"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row["geboortedatum"]); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
            } 
            /*echo $row;*/
            /*echo $resultaat */
        ?>

</body>
</html>
```

ive tried to echo te row and the result beacause i saw there was no echo.
ive tried the query and it's gooed.
the connection is also good.
so i'v no idea how to fix this problem.
see image for the result i get:only the table header without data.
please help me.
thanks in advance

Comment: Why in the world did you try to create your mysql_* functions to bypass errors? There's a reason those functions don't exist. Please use either [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and use them properly.

Comment: Typo: `mysqi_sql_exception` will not catch `mysqli_sql_exception`, the actual `mysqli` exception handling class. Using an IDE with proper highlighting of these issues would help immensely in improving your code's quality in this respect.

Comment: @esqew sorry for the misunderstanding.i've correct the typo but onfortunately it did'nt fix my problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it this way.

```
<?php
session_start();
// Credentials to the DB
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost'; // HOST -> server 
$DATABASE_USER = 'root'; // user -> username we are connecting to
$DATABASE_PASS = ''; // password -> from the user
$DATABASE_NAME = 'pro07'; //DB name

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
// makes the connection to the DB
$connection = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST,$DATABASE_USER,$DATABASE_PASS,$DATABASE_NAME);

// if connection fails
if(mysqli_connect_error()){
    // shows the error
    exit('Connection Error: '.mysqli_connect_error());
}

$result = mysqli_query($connection ,"SELECT id, naam, adres, geslacht, telefoon, 
email, woonplaats, geboortedatum FROM alggegevens");
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Algemene gegevens gedetineerden</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Naam</td>
            <td>Adres</td>
            <td>Geslacht</td>
            <td>Telefoon</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Woonplaats</td>
            <td>Geboortedatum</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=  $row["id"]; ?></td>
            <td><?=  $row["naam"]; ?></td>
            <td><?=  $row["adres"]; ?></td>
            <td><?=  $row["geslacht"]; ?></td>
            <td><?=  $row["telefoon"]; ?></td>
            <td><?=  $row["email"]; ?></td>
            <td><?=  $row["woonplaats"]; ?></td>
            <td><?=  $row["geboortedatum"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You must not close `<table>` before you have printed out the data.
Is the data read correctly? If yes, in this case something of the data must be visible. And if not, at least the empty `<td>` should be visible in the source code.

Answer (score -1):

Your echo should be inside the while loop like

```
 function mysql_query(){

            };
            $resultaat = mysql_query($query);
            function mysql_fetch_array(){

            };
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultaat)) {
    //echo here 
// echo $resultaat;
echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
                
            </tr>';
        ?>
```